# How to iterate over multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, html, angular, selector

I am creating a form that should be able to assign properties to multiple files before those files are processed and imported into my data base. Before the import process I want to know what source the file comes from and which sport they relate to. The form looks as follows on my page:

[image]

As you can see there can be multiple selector on this form, but before I allow the user to processed I want to check that selector have been properly selected, and for all my research I can't find a way to do this anywhere.

For reference my source code for the component and related template are below:

**Component**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-selector-table',
  templateUrl: './selector-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./selector-table.component.css'],
})
export class SelectorTableComponent implements OnInit {
  // Properties
  proceed = false;

  //Inputs
  @Input() singleSource!: boolean;
  @Input() selectedSource!: string;
  @Input() singleSport!: boolean;
  @Input() selectedSport!: string;
  @Input() fileNames!: string[];
  @Input() availableSources!: string[];
  @Input() availableSports!: string[];
  

  // Constructor
  constructor() {}

  readyToProceed() {
    this.proceed = true;
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.availableSources.unshift('Select Source')
    this.availableSports.unshift('Select Sport')    
  }
}
```

**HTML template**

```
<div
  style="
    margin: 8px;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    color: #333;
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
  "
>
  <h2>Selector table</h2>
  <table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; min-width: 50%">
    <tr style="padding-left: 8px; text-align: left; font-weight: bolder">
      <td style="min-width: 40%">File name</td>
      <td>Source</td>
      <td>Sport</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let file of fileNames">
      <td style="text-align: left">{{ file }}</td>
      <td style="text-align: left">
        <div *ngIf="singleSource">
          {{ selectedSource }}
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="!singleSource">
          <select style="min-width: 10rem;" >
            <option *ngFor='let source of availableSources'>{{source}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: left">
        <div *ngIf="singleSport">
          {{ selectedSport }}
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="!singleSport">
          <select style="min-width: 10rem;" >
            <option *ngFor='let sport of availableSports'>{{sport}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button style="margin-top: 20px;" (click)="readyToProceed()">Proceed</button>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may look into angular forms

Comment: You should consider using forms and form validators.

Answer (score 0):

This could be easily achieved by using Forms instead of the table. You can easily validate if the form is valid based on validations defined by angular. Also, you have option to add custom validators if you wish.
Please refer this link for angular reactive forms:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms